# Jekyll post HTML not getting formatted correctly

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am generating my blog using GIT HUB pages ,  some of the posts in the blog do not seem to get rendered properly  while some work .

All the formating and display is lost and the page ends up showing the the actual md file instead of the html.
You can see the issues on the link here http://pratikvasani.github.io/archive/2015/01/16/Valuetype-or-reference-type/

The .md file in question is here https://github.com/pratikvasani/pratikvasani.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-01-16-Valuetype-or-reference-type.md

```
---
layout:     post
title:      Value type
date:       2015-12-25
summary:    Value types.
categories: MVC6 Localization 
---

This looks like a amateur question , but don't be surprised if you get the answer wrong.
There is more to understand in value types and reference types than saying


Value types are data types which are stored on the stack while Reference types are stored on the Heap.

While this is a very popular statement which is used to differentiate value types and reference types , it is not entirely true.
....
```

Could anyone tell me whats wrong ? I have checking the format of the .md file and its correct . The encoding is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an unprintable character at the beginning of the file.
I've created a [PR](https://github.com/pratikvasani/pratikvasani.github.io/pull/1).

You could easily noticed it just by comparing how github processes the markdown: [problematic file](https://github.com/pratikvasani/pratikvasani.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-01-16-Valuetype-or-reference-type.md)
and [other post file](https://github.com/pratikvasani/pratikvasani.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2015-12-07-generic-queries-ddd-cqrs.md).

Answer (score 2):

Your file is `UTF-8 with BOM` encoded. As you can see in [Jekyll documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/#encoding), UTF-8 files must be encoded with no BOM.

Remove the BOM and it works.

Comment: thanks for the link to the documentation , turns out that many editors on windows will add BOM characters by default.